# Labeling selection of OSM layer in QGIS depending on certain tags?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, labeling

I just imported original OSM data to export a pdf-map by assigning graphic attributes to the features I need.

The label tool in QGIS 1.8 allows to select certain features, like I can do with the graphic style. But I do not know and can not find how to label a feature like ref (street-nr) of a certain tag like highway = motorway (especially if all other line elements are labeled by name).

`tags LIKE '%"highway"="motorway"%'`

and then? ref is a feature with an attribute in the column tags.

Another Example: Can I achieve several labeling sizes for different tags like city, town or suburb?

The old labeling menu allows only one label attribution for each layer. Can I select labeling by any attribute?

Thanks for any help and tips concerning the syntax in QGIS attribution and labeling. (The answer: "How to label features in QGIS using SQL statement?" did not help at least)

Answer (score 4):

Using expression-based labeling and CASE WHEN THEN constructs, it should be possible to achieve what you are looking for:

[image]

Different label sizes are currently only possible if you define the label size in attributes and use data-defined labeling.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I could not work out the syntax. The function help list in QGIS 1.8 is empty: "(Hoppla! QGIS kann die Hilfe für die Funktion nicht finden
Die Hilfedatei für Operatoren wurde nicht gefunden.
Sie war weder in Ihrer (de_DE) noch in englischer Sprache verfügbar.
Wenden Sie sich an das QGIS-Entwicklerteam, falls Sie eine ergänzen möchten.)" I was not able to sort out, how to define to use the "ref"="A 1" tag from "tags" when "highway"="motorway"